# How can I use regular expressions in Textpad to remove anything, line by line, after specified characters?

Tags: regex, textpad

Suppose I have the following text in Textpad:

```
kwejkewrjl:ksajdlakj

e833ekjh:skdjkahak

2098e123809:ksjdkas

dkjwhfdkjqhio:skjddksjal

98a09asfdsaok:kwqjeo912ui
```

I would like to remove all characters from each line that occur after the colon.
The new text should be:

```
kwejkewrjl:

e833ekjh:

2098e123809:

dkjwhfdkjqhio:

98a09asfdsaok:
```

Comment: In notepad++ I would just find `:.*` and replace with `:`, make sure `regular expression` is checked and `. matches newline` is not checked. Perhaps textpad works similarly?

Comment: finding `:[^\n\r]*` and replacing with `:` should be pretty fail-proof regardless of DOTALL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

Find:

```
:.*
```

Replace with:

```
:
```

Just did this in TextPad on one of my servers.

Comment: Most helpful of these types of questions I've seen thus far! I had to replace `,,XX/` pattern where `XX` could be any number, and this enabled me to figure out that `,,.*/` would do the trick. The brackets make it rather complicated when starting out with these...