# TextPad - regular expression - How to find longer value (character) than

Tags: regex, textpad

Please how to find longer value with "regular expression" in the TextPad application?

Thanks a lot
Libi

Comment: This may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858334/how-can-i-use-regular-expressions-in-textpad-to-remove-anything-line-by-line-a

Comment: I have the value "hanah2015"  but this value has 9 chars and it can have only 8chars.
So in the data file I need to find all values which are longer then 8 chars.

Comment: For example from the list find the  <PID>hanah2015</PID>:

list of values:
<PID>ibor2351</PID>
<PID>lili0158</PID>
<PID>hanah2015</PID>
<PID>david158</PID>

Answer (score 0):

> So in the data file I need to find all values which are **longer then 8 chars**

This regex might be what you want:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,}
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/jOyzlE/1).

Depending on the source file, the regex may need some adjustment.